# Subsitute a matrix M by (-M) in SymPy and display it unambiguously

Tags: python, jupyter, sympy

Suppose I have the following matrix expression:

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing(use_unicode=True)
x = sympy.MatrixSymbol('x', 2, 2)
y = sympy.MatrixSymbol('y', 2, 2)

a = x * y
```

I would like to substitute the second matrix with the same matrix times negative one:

```
a.subs(y, (-y))
```

If `x` and `y` were regular SymPy symbols, this would show as `-xy`. But in this case it shows as `x - y`. Even though upon substitution of matrix values it evaluates correctly (i.e. as `-xy`), this demonstration quickly becomes ambiguous. How do I make it display correctly?

When `sympy.init_printing()` is not called, it displays unambiguously as `x\*(-y)`.

I use this in Jupyter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in SymPy's LaTeX printer: it does not consider that `MatMul(Integer(-1), MatrixSymbol(...))` needs parentheses in a product.

Until the bug is fixed, a workaround is to use "pretty" printing instead of LaTeX:

```
sympy.init_printing(use_latex=False)
```

resulting in `x⋅(-y)`. Pretty-print is generally more readable than `str` output like `x*(-y)`.

---

[The big is fixed in the current master branch](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15439) and therefore should not appear in SymPy versions above 1.3.